# Why do I get a number instead of a Unicode character?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::wcout << '\u00E1' << std::endl;
}
```

But [it outputs `50081` when compiled with GCC 4.8.1](http://ideone.com/e6zXCy).

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I certainly wouldn't expect a number to be output. What's going on?

Comment: -1 you're compiling a different code

Comment: OK <3. Then -1 for not using `-Wall -Werror` (`/W4 /WX` in VC++)

Comment: @Abyx: [Despite the resultant warning, the output is still the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92c81c1a5af4b943) and the question stands "why is it numeric? this is crazy biznis".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a bug in g++. The type of `'\u00E1'` is `char`, but g++ is treating it as an `int`. clang++ gets this right.

Consider this related program (with an overloaded `type_of` function to detect the type of the literals):

```
#include <iostream>

const char *type_of(char) { return "char"; }
const char *type_of(int)  { return "int";  }

int main()
{
   std::cout << "type_of('x')  = " << type_of('x') << "\n";
   std::cout << "type_of('xy') = " << type_of('xy') << "\n";           // line 9
   std::cout << "type_of('\u00E1')  = " << type_of('\u00E1') << "\n";  // line 10
   std::cout << "type_of('\u0100')  = " << type_of('\u0100') << "\n";  // line 11
}
```

When I compile this with g++ 4.7.2, I get these warnings:

```
c.cpp:9:47: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
c.cpp:10:52: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
c.cpp:11:52: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

and this output:

```
type_of('x')  = char
type_of('xy') = int
type_of('á')  = int
type_of('Ā')  = int
```

With clang++ 3.0, I get just two warnings:

```
c.cpp:9:47: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   std::cout << "type_of('xy') = " << type_of('xy') << "\n";
                                              ^
c.cpp:11:52: warning: character unicode escape sequence too long for its type
   std::cout << "type_of('\u0100')  = " << type_of('\u0100') << "\n";
```

and this output:

```
type_of('x')  = char
type_of('xy') = int
type_of('á')  = char
type_of('Ā')  = char
```

The character literal `'\u00E1'` has just one *c-char-sequence*, which happens to be a *universal-character-name*, so it's of type `char`, but g++ is incorrectly treating it as a multi-character constant of type `int`. clang++ correctly treats it as an ordinary character literal of type `char`.

The value of such a character literal whose value is outside the range of `char` is implementation-defined, but it's still of type `char`.

Since you're writing to `std::wcout`, you probably wanted a wide character literal: `L'\u00E1'`, which is of type `char_t`, rather than `'\u00E1'`, which (if your compiler handles it correctly) is of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be  compiler bug.

According to the Standard (2.14.3/1) `'\u00E1'` is an ordinary character literal (it doesn't have `u`, `U` or `L` prefix), which contains a single *c-char* (which is a *universal-character-name*), thus it has type `char`.

So `std::wcout << '\u00E1'` should use `operator<<(char)` and print a single character.

Instead it takes that *universal-character-name*, converts it to a UTF-8 encoded sequence and gets a *multicharacter literal* '\xC3\xA1' which is an `int` with value 50081:

```
'\u00E1' -> '\xC3\xA1' -> 50081
```

Comment: Doesn't `2.14.3/5` require such a conversion?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's still of type `char`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: So the conversion happens too late to effectively produce more than one _c-char_ for `2.14.3/1` to kick in? Genuinely asking to double check before I delete my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I see no mention of a conversion in 2.14.3/5.

Comment: Well it's hard so say how *encodings* can be applied to single characters, not to byte sequences. I mean we have a single codepoint and we can encode it into a sequence of bytes, but here we should *encode* it in either `char` or `int`.

Comment: @Keith: `s/conversion/translation/`. "A universal-character-name is translated to the encoding, in the appropriate execution character set, of the character named."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, and paragraph 5 says nothing about the *type* of the result. The type is specified in paragraph 1, and nothing in paragraph 5 changes that. (It's mildly interesting that the type of an integer literal can depend on its value, but the type of a character literal depends only on its syntactic form.)

Comment: @Keith: I guess I wasn't clear. I was proposing the remote possibility that you take the `char` with the _universal-character-name_ in it, apply `/5`'s translation to obtain a `char` with multiple `c-char`s in it perhaps (seems unlikely but this is what I'm asking to double check), at which point `/1` kicks in resulting in an `int`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't think so. Paragraph 1 says that a character literal with one *c-char* has type `char`. I see no ambiguity that would allow it to be of a different type. The *value* is ambiguous; that's what paragraph 5 is for.